# Keep Qt tooltip open

Tags: qt, tooltip

Windows tooltips do close after a certain amount of time (5-32 sec afaik). In Qt they seem to be set to 10 sec autoclose. Is there any way I can alter this behaviour? Qt docs remain silent about that.

Maybe there are any custom tooltip classes around which I can make sticky? Qt Creator uses some sort of custom ToolTips for debugging.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I googled "qt tooltip delay" and the second link sent me to the Nokia FAQ, where it explains that the tooltip timer is hardcoded, and gives a "workaround" for that here:
http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_can_i_change_the_timeout_period_for_a_qtooltip

Yet the first comment on that says that it only works if you want to make the tooltip delay shorter, not longer.
The first link in my search suggest modifying the class yourself, but that's probably not a good idea, albeit it might be a temporary solution, since it seems the suggestion for this feature was sent ages ago (since before Nokia bought them), and it hasn't been implemented yet.